# Should my oven have a hole like this?

Tags: oven, heat

I moved to a new apartment and under the far left burner is a hole into the oven:

[image: Hole]

That is my pizza stone you are seeing through the hole.

I understand that the oven needs some ventilation, but this seems like it would cause a lot of heat loss. Indeed the burner and any pan sitting there get quite warm while the oven is in use, I can boil water with the excess heat if a kettle is left there long enough (and the oven is very hot, like when I bake bread).

Comment: Agree that it's a duplicate.   brenzo, look at the answer on the other question, it will enlighten you.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like a opening below a surface burner; I have seen stoves that vent that oven like that.Use the heat if you can.